# nodetool rebuild returned "Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range"

Tags: migration, cassandra

We are migrating self hosted cassandra 3.11.6 to self hosted cassandra with k8ssandra-operator using cassandra 3.11.7.

At some point of the migration we had to stop it due to other unrelated incident. After resuming it and running rebuild on all the nodes 3 nodes started rebuilding data again.

For 2 remaining nodes I am getting this error:

`Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (6296969270738431410,6299853300486273791] in keyspace system_distributed`

System auth, traces, distributed were altered and are using `NetworkTopologyStrategy` with replication factors for `dc1: 3` and `dc2: 3`.

Any idea why that could happen and how can I solve this issue? Why 3 nodes are working fine and only these 2 have problems? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, Cassandra is unable to reach replicas to stream data for the given token range. The most common reasons for this error are:

- replicas (nodes) are unavailable,
- replication issues, and
- network issues.

If a replica (pod) is unavailable or down for whatever reason, the initiating node will not be able to stream data from that replica. You need to investigate why the replica is unavailable, unresponsive or down and resolve it.

If the replication is not configured correctly, the initiating node will also not be able to find a source to stream the data from. For example, a keyspace may have been configured to have replicas in DC `Dc2` (notice the incorrect capitalisation) instead of `dc2` or `DC2`. You will need to review the replication settings on the affected keyspace(s) and fix as appropriate.

Finally, the initiating node will not be able to find a source to stream from if replicas (or pods) are unreachable because of network connectivity issues.

You need to identify the root cause and resolve it before you can restart the `rebuild` operation. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could that also happen in the meantime on migration? Like it was working and then stopped. I also checked the replication factors and they are all correct. :/ Do you have any other idea?

Comment: It can happen at anytime -- migration or not. If a replica becomes unavailable/unresponsive or there is a network glitch, streaming operations will be affected. Cheers!